# Java generics - what is the difference?

Tags: java, generics

Consider that I have following interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends Number>
```

In another class I want to declare a method like this:

```
public <T extends MyInterface<?>> void abc(T a);
```

Is this a correct way? Or maybe should I write:

```
public <T extends MyInterface<T>> void abc(T a);
```

What is the difference between these two declarations?

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve, your use case and what inheritance model you want, then we will be able to help.

Comment: Also I don't think the second declaration is what you want. If T=MyClass then the declaration becomes public <MyClass extends MyInterface<MyClass>>, Is that what you need in your use case?

Comment: I was achieve my goal with first declaration but I saw the second one somewhere and I just wonder about the differences between them. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some interfaces are intended to take the implementing class as the generic type.

For instance, the `Comparable` interface is usually implemented as:

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
```

because then the method

```
int compareTo(T o);
```

declared in `Comparable` can be used to compare an instance of `MyClass` to another instance of the same class.

Other interfaces have a generic parameter of a different type. For instance, `List<T>`, where `T` indicates the type of object contained within the list.

If you declare a method with:

```
public <T extends MyInterface<T>> void abc(T a);
```

then you're saying that the class `T` implements the interface `MyInterface` in the way that classes implement the `Comparable` interface - with themselves as the generic type. That might or might not be appropriate depending on what `MyInterface` actually is.

If you declare a method with:

```
public <T extends MyInterface<?>> void abc(T a):
```

then you not placing any constraint on the generic type in `T`'s implementation of `MyInterface`.

The other option is

```
public void abc(MyInterface<?> a);
```

which is the simplest way to write a method that will accept any implementation of `MyInterface`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Now I understand the difference